# Automatically zoom on a certain position of an image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

Is it possible to automatically zoom in an image to a certain position of the image itself?

I think that could be possible even with the animations but i don't figure out how could i get the specific point of the image (and then make it on mobile as well).

I'll make an example to be more explicit:<br
-In the following link i'd like to zoom into the person's eye automatically (no buttons), if you are wondering why it's because i'd like to use something like that as a preloader.

My questions are:

1. Which method could i use to zoom?
2. How am i able to indicate (and calculate) that specific point/pixel?

Link of the example:

https://jsfiddle.net/eL1sbotx/

Code: (requested by StackOverFlow[Also found on the link above])

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="preloader">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    background-color: #000;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: "Roboto";
}
.preloader{
  height:100%;
  background-image: url("http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/category-images/118.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: look at background-size maybe : https://jsfiddle.net/49h67axj/

Comment: This link will help you out... https://code-boxx.com/image-zoom-css-javascript/